# Let $V_1,V_2$ be subspaces of $V$. If $\dim(V_1+V_2)=\dim(V_1 \cap V_2) + 1$ then prove that $ V1 \subseteq V2 $ or $V2 \subseteq V1$.

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

We know that $\dim(V_1+V_2)=\dim(V_1)+\dim(V_2)-\dim(V_1 \cap V_2)$,
But $\dim(V_1+V2)=\dim(V1 \cap V2)+ 1$ (given),

Now if we assume that $V_1 \subseteq V_2$ , $V_1 \cap V_2= V_1$,
Then at one side it will be $\dim(V_1)$ while other side it will be $\dim(V_1)+1$.
How it is possible?

Comment: The left side is $\dim(V_1+V_2)$, not $\dim(V_1)$.

Comment: Yes but if we equate the two equations ie $dim (V1 \cap V2)+1=dim(V1)+dim(V2)-dim(V1 \cap V2)$

Comment: Then what? If $V_1 \subseteq V_2$, this becomes $\dim(V_1)+1=\dim(V_2)$.

Comment: Yes Sorry I made mistake. But still not able to prove

Answer (score 0):

As for why this is possible, here is an example: Take $V_1=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $V_2=\{0\}\times \mathbb{R}$. Then you can check easily that all the statements are satisfied with $\dim V_2=1$.

For a hint for the prove: Try to extend a basis for $V_1\cap V_2$ to a basis of $V_1+V_2$. Imagine what would happen if none of the inclusions is satisfied.